# in MySQL, can I "select *" in a view, without the view expanding the field list

Tags: mysql, view

when I say:

```
create view myView select * from myTable where ...
```

MySQL creates the view with * expanded to explicitly name every field in myTable.

Is there any way to get it to preserve the '*', so that if I later add a field to myTable, the view will automatically include that new field?

Comment: The answer is "no", but "no" is too short for a comment.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  Clearly, that wasn't the answer I was hoping for. ... but it was one I expected. :-(

Hmmm, since I have 3 similar views -- different joins and where clauses -- on 4 base tables and counting,  maybe I'll have to script something to delete and recreate the views when I change the base table.   Hmmm.